# MigraDoc add image to table from stream

Tags: c#, .net, image, pdf, migradoc

I've been using MigraDoc to generate PDFs and I've got the layout of everything working great except for adding in images.  for the part of the program we're generating these PDFs for we're using a program that only saves their information as XML and from there am able to convert the XML into System.Drawing.Image objects.  The problem I'm running into is somehow getting the System.Drawing.Image objects now into my PDFs.

Answer (score 4):

MigraDoc was designed to work with filenames. So one option is saving the stream to a temporary file and then use the filename.

Or modify the MigraDoc source code to work with image objects - such a patch can be found on the PDFsharp forum.

BTW: The downvote is not from me. Maybe someone thinks that very little effort was used to post the question here.

**Update (January 16, 2016):** With version 1.50 (currently available as beta version only, but it is pretty stable) you can pass images in the filename: the filename will contain the image bytes using BASE64 encoding.
It's a bit of a hack, but should work for all scenarios.
Sample code here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_FilelessImages.ashx

So MigraDoc still uses filenames only, but it is no longer necessary to save images in temporary files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably have to go with the temp file for the moment.  I might try editing the source code I later, I'm just working with crazy work firewalls that prevent me from going to those forums for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where this solution started working, but I usually solve this problem with simple method to convert stream into virtual file path.

```
internal static string LoadImageFromBytes(byte[] cData)
{
    return $"base64:{Convert.ToBase64String(cData)}";
}
```

And then use it in `AddImage()` method:

```
row[0].AddImage(LoadImageFromBytes(byteArray))
```

Comment: It started working in the beta phase of version 1.50 (as indicated in the old answer from 2014/2016). It didn't work yet when the question was asked in 2014.

Comment: Thank you for information. Now it's easiest solution for me.